# JavaScript make specific letter a different color?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a specific letter: "*" be red in a line of JavaScript coding that I am working with.
The following is my original:

```
function init(){
    var inp = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
        if(inp[i].type == 'text','tel','number', 'email') {
            inp[i].setAttribute('rel',inp[i].defaultValue)
            inp[i].setAttribute('style', 'color: grey;')
            inp[i].onfocus = function() {
                if(this.value == this.getAttribute('rel')) {
                    this.value = '';
                    this.setAttribute('style', 'color: black;')
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

In order to make a specific letter red, would I change it to?

```
function init(){
    var inp = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
        if(inp[i].type == 'text','tel','number', 'email') {
            inp[i].setAttribute('rel',inp[i].defaultValue)
            inp[i].setAttribute('style', 'color: grey;')
            inp[i].onfocus = function() {
                if(this.value == this.getAttribute('rel')) {
                    this.value = '';
                    this.setAttribute('style', 'color: black;')

                if(this.value == this.getAttribute('*')) {
                    this.setAttribute('style', 'color: red;')

                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: you can't style parts of the text in an `input` only the input itself. Please explain your goals in more detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... because I am really bored, [I ended up doing what you wanted using javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/eTEvQ/2/).

It uses Mootools, but it should provide enough inspiration for you to recreate it using jQuery if you so desire.

```
function reposition() {
    var position = inputEl.getPosition();
    var occludeLabel = inputEl.value;
    occludeLabel = occludeLabel.replace(/\*/g, '<span class="red">*</span>', 'g');
    occludeEl.setStyles({
        top: position.y + 1,
        left: position.x + 1
    });
    occludeEl.set('html', occludeLabel);
}
```

Basically, every time you blur the input, a div containing the input box's value is placed over the input box, occluding the text. I ran a simple `.replace()` to replace all asterisks with a span that would turn its contents red.

Please see this jsfiddle for all of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/eTEvQ/2/

Comment: Further optimizations could be made to the `.replace()`, so that it takes all consecutive asterisks and places it all in one span. Right now, I'm putting each `*` into its own span.

Comment: Hi @julian-h-lam, your solution is very interesting but is there a way to have the coloration directly while typing (and not have to leave the box to update the view?). I guess not as it would mask the typing cursor?

Answer (score 0):

You can style only the elements but not the attributes..

This line does not make any sense..

```
this.value == this.getAttribute('*')
```

***** is not a valid attribute name

Also **this** here is the current input element in Question..

You can set a color for the input element as a whole but not for specific characters inside them

Comment: So it is impossible to style specific letters within an input?

Comment: This is weird to me, because I have most definitely seen it been done before. https://m.mittromney.com/donate/mobile-donate

Comment: That is the placeholder in Question.. Try typing * in there and check if the color changes to red

Comment: No, it does not. What does this tell me?

Comment: This tells you that you cannot change the colour of a single character in an input box. You can change the colour of all characters only. Alternatively, you could do some js that dynamically creates a div on the fly that occludes the input box, styled however you'd like.

Comment: If you are trying to emulate what you have seen elsewhere, you should inspect the code and see what they are doing. Indeed, there are inputs on that website, but they are all wrapped in <div>s with <label>s and <span>s absolutely positioned on top to show the red *. Once you focus the input, those elements are hidden and you simply type into the input.